# Referencing to a value in the next row in an if statement

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I'm working with a dataframe of which i want to remove the first and the last row of a group.
For some reason doing so with the first row works fine, but when I use the same code for the last row I get an error.

```
head(pilott0)
   Sensor0 Treatment Testnr RPM index waveperiod
1 890.2380      T1_S  T1_1S 780   298         NA
2 928.1808      T1_S  T1_1S 780   636        338
3 923.4647      T1_S  T1_1S 780   975        339
4 929.1885      T1_S  T1_1S 780  1313        338
5 885.0237      T1_S  T1_1S 780  1652        339
6 918.6435      T1_S  T1_1S 780  1988        336
```

I used the following code for changing the waveperiod of a new Testnr to NA, which worked.

```
for(i in 2:nrow(pilott0)){
  if(pilott0$Testnr[i] != pilott0$Testnr[i-1]){
    pilott0$waveperiod[i]=NA}}
```

While using the same method to change the last waveperiod of a Testnr gave an error

```
for(i in 2:nrow(pilott0)){
  if(pilott0$Testnr[i] != pilott0$Testnr[i+1]){
    pilott0$waveperiod[i]=NA}}

Error in if (pilott0$Testnr[i] != pilott0$Testnr[i + 1]) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Since the first waveperiod value is a NA already i chose to use teh following code for removing the first and last row of each Testnr.

```
pilott0=subset(pilott0,pilott0$waveperiod != "NA")
```

Comment: You have a mismatch between the limits of your `for` loop and the logic within.  You need `1:(nrow(pilott0)-1)` in your second `for` loop.  Even better, use `lag` and `lead` and avoid the loops altogether.  And almost certainly get an increase in execution speed.

Comment: Remember `NA` is not a string and cannot be comparable with `==` or `!=`. Use `is.na(...)` or `!is.na(...)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Consider `ave` with `seq_along` and `length` to remove first and last values by `Testnr` group.

```r
pilott0 <- within(
    pilott0, {
        grp_num <- ave(1:nrow(pilott0), Testnr, FUN=seq_along)
        grp_cnt <- ave(1:nrow(pilott0), Testnr, FUN=length)

        waveperiod <- ifelse(grp_num %in% c(1, grp_cnt), NA_integer_, waveperiod)

        rm(grp_num, grp_cnt)
    }
)
```